# File Uploading To table when Available in Path

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

i have to design a **SSIS** Package which load flatfile **whenever it is available**
from the path to the table of a database. 
how can i implement it on Production Please suggest.

I Use SQL Agent to execute it. will it be possible only using sql or C#, **WITHOUT** any third
party tool. ?

Thanks

Comment: always provide information, what have you tried to accomplish the task and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a tutorial below. At last after deploying your package you can create a job in SSMS which will run at a specified time to execute your package.

To complete this objective following tasks are required.
1. **Foreach Loop Container:** To iterate over a user configured directory for files.
2. **Expression Task:** To update a variable if file exists.

**Steps**
1. First goto **Solution Explorer** double click on **Project.params** and create a parameter *FolderPath* of type string, put value like E:\DataDir\SourceFiles.
2. Create user variables *FileNameFromFolder* (String), *FileToSearch* (String) assign value that you want to check and create a variable *IsFound* (Boolean).
3. Drag and drop a *Foreach Loop Container* from the SSIS Toolbox under Containers section.
4. Double click on the *Foreach Loop Container* on the left hand side of Foreach Loop Editor click on the **Collection**. On the right side set Enumerator as **Foreach File Enumerator**, now for the Expression click on the three dots which will open a Property Expression Editor. Select Directory as property and for expression select *@[$Project::FolderPath]*. Click OK.
[image: Foreach Loop Editor Expression Property]
5. Now in Foreach Loop Editor for the value of Files set ***.txt**, for the value of *Retrieve file name* select Name only, normally we select Fully Qualified as it returns file name with the complete path. Check the *Traverse subfolders* if there can be more than one folder inside a folder.
[image: Foreach properties]
6. On the left select **Variable Mappings**, on the right side select *User::FileNameFromFolder* which will automatically get Index as 0. The file names from the *FolderPath* will be assigned one by one to the *FileNameFromFolder* variable. Click OK.
[image: Foreach Loop Variable Mappings]
7. Drag and drop a *Expression Task* inside the *Foreach Loop Container* from the SSIS toolbox present under the section **Common**.
8. Double click on the *Expression Task*, in the Expression Builder write following code. Click OK.

```
@[User::IsFound] =  @[User::FileNameFromFolder] == @[User::FileToSearch] ? TRUE : FALSE
```

[image]
9. The Code above compares the file name that we want to check with the file name from the folder, if both are matched it sets *IsFound* to True (File Exists).
10. Now the value of IsFound can be used with precedence constraint according to need.